# Pandas DataFrame formatting to get expected output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following Pandas `DataFrame`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'session' : ["1","1","2","2","3","3"],
                'path'  : ["p1","p2","p1","p2","p2","p3"], 'seconds' : ["20","21","132","10","24","45"]})
```

I need to get an output like the following. (Pages as columns, sessions as rows and seconds in each cell.)

```
session,p1,p2,p3
1,20,21,0
2,132,10,0
3,0,24,45
```

What I have done so far.

```
In [76]: wordlist = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
In [77]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('session').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.path)))
In [78]: df2 #I have renamed the columns
Out[78]: 

                  path
        session       
        1        p1,p2
        2        p1,p2
        3        p2,p3

In [79]: df3 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('session').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.seconds.astype(str))))
In [80]: df3 #I have renamed the columns
Out[80]: 
                   path
        session        
        1         20,21
        2        132,10
        3         24,45
```

The following just gives the boolean result. I need to get my expected output. Any help on this?

```
In [84]: pd.DataFrame({name : df2["path"].str.contains(name) for name in wordlist})
Out[84]: 
            p1    p2     p3
session                    
1         True  True  False
2         True  True  False
3        False  True   True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pivot table:

```
df.pivot(index='session', columns='path')
```

Then replace all the Nan's with zeros:

```
df2 = df1.fillna(0)
```

This gives you the following output:

```
        seconds        
path         p1  p2  p3
session                
1            20  21   0
2           132  10   0
3             0  24  45
```

Then you might want to drop the multiindex column:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Yielding your desired solution (sans commas):

```
path      p1  p2  p3
session             
1         20  21   0
2        132  10   0
3          0  24  45
```

Finally you can convert it to comma-separated string using `StringIO`:

```
import StringIO
s = StringIO.StringIO()
df1.to_csv(s)
print s.getvalue()
```

With the following output:

```
session,p1,p2,p3
1,20,21,0
2,132,10,0
3,0,24,45
```